Need help to find a dendrology question
Hi I have over 200 people around the world who are willing to collect pictures and/or measurements from trees. The question is, what is the one question we can answer with that information? what is the ONE question in dendrology this information could give an answer to?

Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. This site looks for questions that are able to be answered with factual references and as such are single questions. This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts as per the don't ask page

I don't think this is a good fit for this site, but you might try searching the key words "citizen science" plus your interests to find projects open to contributors.

I'm not sure that I understand. What question do you want to answer? What do you find interesting? Climate change response? Why not turn to your volunteers for suggestions?
